What does the _blazor?id= part of a Blazor Server URL mean?
I have a Blazor Server web app. When I look at the DevTools in my browser I see a lot of GET requests to URLS like https://mysite/_blazor?id=123456789&_=123456789 for one page load.
What are these GET requests doing? What is the id parameter? And what about the _?
Is this the ID of the connection? Is this SignalR doing its thing?

May I know if you have got any chance to check my reply? It will be great if you can share more detailed information for us to better investigate this issue. Thanks for your cooperation.


What are these GET requests doing? This format of https://mysite/blazor?id=123456789&=123456789 requests is a negotiation process.

I created a brand new project and didn't see '&_'. But it doesn't matter, this is a parameter and will be used in the negotiation process. Like below:

The official default template, may not be very well understood, it is recommended to create a custom hub, connect again, you will see the process of negotiate, and the following screenshot is the same, after the negotiation is successful, WebSocket will be used to communicate.


